# How django time zone works with model.field's auto_now_add

Tags: django, timezone

I suppose time zone management was added to Django 1.4, so the problem is quite new.

I used a simple model

```
class Sample(models.Model):
    ...
    date_generated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
```

When I try to retrieve a newly created record its fails.

```
min_datetime = datetime.now() - timedelta(seconds = 300)
sample = Sample.objects.get(date_generated__gte = min_datetime)
```

and the server issues a warning.

```
DateTimeField received a naive DateTime (2012-06-29 15:02:15.074000) while time zone support is active.
```

I figured out two solutions to that problem.

1. Disable time zone management in settings.py

   ```
    USE_TZ = False
   ```

but this is not always desirable.
2. changing

```
    date_generated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
```

to

```
    date_generated = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
```

is the solution that keeps time zone management working

Answer (score 39):

Use timezone utils of django

```
from django.utils import timezone
date_generated = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Comment: For others viewing this thread: note how the answer says `now` and not `now()`. The second would evaluate while loading the server, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 25):

The problem is on your end: `datetime.now()` is not TZ aware, so you're the one feeding in a naive TZ. See the [Django docs on this issue](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects). The reason it works when setting `default=datetime.now` is that you're forcing the value to a naive datetime, so when you later compare it with another naive datetime, there's no problem.

You need to get "now" the following way:

```
import datetime
from django.utils.timezone import utc

now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)
```

Comment: Does this mean I can't just use auto_now or auto_now_add if I have USE_TZ = True?

Comment: It seems `auto_now` and `auto_now_add` inherently use `datetime.now`. It seems an odd omission on Django's part to insert TZ aware facilities into Django, yet miss this pretty major one, but the fate of these two kwargs has been debated for a long time. My reasoning is that they're being left in for backwards compatibility (and to avoid push-back), but don't expect them to get any love. Just set the `default` kwarg with `utcnow` and don't worry about `auto_now` or `auto_now_add`, if you want TZ aware datetimes.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I don't think "default" would work in replacing "auto_now" though since the latter always update the time for every save while "default" is only when the field has no value.

Comment: An even faster way to get "now"...
`from django.utils.timezone import now as utcnow`.  `now = utcnow()` will then give you the same result as @ChrisPratt gave.

Comment: django 1.4.5 shows auto_now or auto_now_add uses timezone.now() , not datetime.now() so its safe to use them.

Comment: @eugene: they already did. The problem the OP was having was that auto_now and auto_now_add *were* storing TZ aware datetimes, but when he later tried to filter them, he was using a naive datetime.

Comment: @Chris: I was trying to update the current status of django regarding the comment `It seems auto_now and auto_now_add inherently use datetime.now` made at jul 11'12. yes.. OP was implying auto_now and auto_now_add were storing TZ aware datetimes yes. However I was confused with dannyroa and your comment about not being able to use auto_now when use_tz = True

Answer (score 10):

Be careful setting a `DateTimeField` default value of `datetime.now()`, as that will compute a single value when Apache/nginx loads Django (or when you start the development server), and all subsequent records will receive that value.

Always use `auto_now_add` for that reason.

Comment: Just use `default=datetime.now` without brackets.